# Getting user and audit log fromMicrosoft grapgh API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

You can get all users and expand different properties with a single call to  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users. Is there a way to make this call and include audit log as I dont want to make a single call for each user?

Answer (score 0):

You can batch your request into a single call:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching

Comment: Could you add an example of how to include audit log for a user in a batch request?